# What does !!: mean in bash?

Tags: bash, touch, syntax

Watching a video (https://vimeo.com/56166857 & https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9CTfGS0gEOk @ 1m:34s), the presenter (TJ Holowaychuk) wrote:

```
touch !!:2{...}
```

I can't find what `!!:2` means anywhere.

I get the (repeat the previous command) `!!` but, the meaning of

```
!!:2
```

I don't know, can't find an answer for and the search here returned no results for, so ... I'm stuck.

**Context:**

to create several directories at once, he wrote:

```
mkdir -p lib/{login,signup,users,posts}
```

to create the same files in each of those directories, he wrote:

```
touch !!:2/{package.json,index.json}
```

The output was:

```
touch lib/{login,signup,users,posts}/{package.json,index.json}
```

The result was:

The two files were created in each of the directories.

Comment: @StephenRauch yes, except that the `!!:/anything` as described by the OP is invalid syntax and returns `-bash: /: unrecognized history modifier`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You've misread what the presenter entered. This is what is actually given on the video:

```
mkdir -p lib/{login,signup,users,posts}
touch !!:2/{package.json,index.json}
```

This extends the `!!` instruction to repeat the previous command, but the `:2` modifier says use the second argument. So, here `!!:2` is the `lib/{login,signup,users,posts}` component.

Comment: sorry, left out the "2" it was a part of my wtf is that confusion.
adding it now.
so ... the colon then is an argument separator ... like, do 1, do 2 like the bash semicolon?

Comment: @iletras in the manual, "_`!!` Refer to the previous command.  This is a synonym for `!-1`._" and "_Word designators are used to select desired words from the event.  A :  separates  the event  specification from the word designator. [...] Words are numbered  from  the  beginning  of  the
       line, with the first word being denoted by 0 (zero)._"